How to calculate Minimum Mean square error (MMSE) of an estimated value from the given data?
I feel this question is really basic, but I am confused regarding the methodology.
I have to estimate a parameter $g$ from the observed values $k(g)$, and I have the PDF $f(g|k)$.
It is given that minimum mean-squared error (MMSE) estimator can be found as:
$$\hat{g}(k)=\int_{_-\infty}^{\infty} g~f(g|k)~\partial{d}g$$
which I found using numerical integration and now I have several values of $\hat{g}$ corresponding to various values of $g$.
Mean square error (MSE) is given by $$\mathbb{E}_{G|K}[(g-\hat{g}(k))^2].$$
Now my question is:
To calculate the average value of MSE numerically can I simply average out the obtained numerical values as $$\frac{1}{N}\Sigma(g-\hat{g}(h))^2$$, where $N$ is the total number of $g$ estimate values available (total iterations). However, If i do mean like this, then what about the mean is given by:
(continuous) $$\int xf(x)\text{d}x$$ and (discrete) $$\Sigma_i x_i P(x=x_i),$$ where PDF/PMF is also taken care of while calculating the mean.
Should I need to do numerical integration as $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(g-\hat{g}(h))^2f(g|y)\partial g?$$ However, I do not think this will give correct values as for a given estimated numerical value $\hat{g}(k)$, I am going to integrate over the entire range of $g$ in numerical integration.
This question was earlier asked on Cross Validated but owing to no response I have deleted the question there and I am asking it here.
